# Error 401 Unauthorized Trying to make Amplify.API.get request to an API Gateway endpoint

Tags: flutter, dart, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to connect an existing Amazon API Gateway resource to the Amplify libraries in Flutter App by referencing its API endpoint (api-clc) and setting AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS authorization in the amplifyconfiguration file, and getting an error 401 Unauthorized

```
GET call failed: ApiException {
  "message": "{\"message\":\"Unauthorized\"}",
  "underlyingException": "HTTP Status code: 401"
}
```

**amplifyconfiguration.dart:**

```
const amplifyconfig = ''' {
    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/2.0",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "api": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsAPIPlugin": {
                "pocagendaclc": {
                    "endpointType": "GraphQL",
                    "endpoint": [*******************],
                    "region": "us-east-1",
                    "authorizationType": "API_KEY",
                    "apiKey": ["************"]
                },
                "api-clc": {
                    "endpointType": "REST",
                    "endpoint": "https://***********",
                    "region": "us-east-1",
                    "authorizationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
               }

            }
        }
    },
    "auth": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsCognitoAuthPlugin": {
                "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/0.1.0",
                "Version": "0.1.0",
                "IdentityManager": {
                    "Default": {}
                },
                "AppSync": {
                    "Default": {
                        "ApiUrl": [*************],
                        "Region": "us-east-1",
                        "AuthMode": "API_KEY",
                        "ApiKey": [**********],
                        "ClientDatabasePrefix": "pocagendaclc_API_KEY"
                    },
                    "pocagendaclc_AWS_IAM": {
                        "ApiUrl": [************],
                        "Region": "us-east-1",
                        "AuthMode": "AWS_IAM",
                        "ClientDatabasePrefix": "pocagendaclc_AWS_IAM"
                    }
                },
                "CredentialsProvider": {
                    "CognitoIdentity": {
                        "Default": {
                            "PoolId": [***************],
                            "Region": "us-east-1"
                        }
                    }
                },`your text`
                "CognitoUserPool": {
                    "Default": {
                        "PoolId": [*************],
                        "AppClientId": [*************],
                        "Region": "us-east-1"
                    }
                },
                "Auth": {
                    "Default": {
                        "authenticationFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH",
                        "mfaConfiguration": "OFF",
                        "mfaTypes": [
                            "SMS"
                        ],
                        "passwordProtectionSettings": {
                            "passwordPolicyMinLength": 8,
                            "passwordPolicyCharacters": []
                        },
                        "signupAttributes": [
                            "EMAIL"
                        ],
                        "socialProviders": [],
                        "usernameAttributes": [
                            "EMAIL",
                            "PHONE_NUMBER"
                        ],
                        "verificationMechanisms": [
                            "EMAIL"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}''';
```

**my Function: **

```
Future<void> getTodo() async {
  
  try {
    final restOperation = Amplify.API.get(
      '/agenda-medica/especialidades',
       queryParameters: {
        'codHospitales': 'CLC',
      },
      apiName: 'api-clc',
      );
    final response = await restOperation.response;
    print('GET call succeeded: ${response.decodeBody()}');
  } on ApiException catch (e) {
    print('GET call failed: $e');
  }
}
```

The Authorizer is setting up already in the Api Gateway console
[image]
[image]

And Choose the source for my API Keys:
[image]

Im also try whith "authorizationType": "NONE"

```
"api": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsAPIPlugin": {
                "pocagendaclc": {
                    "endpointType": "GraphQL",
                    "endpoint": [-************],
                    "region": "us-east-1",
                    "authorizationType": "API_KEY",
                    "apiKey": [-************]
                },
                "api-clc": {
                    "endpointType": "REST",
                    "endpoint": [-************],
                    "region": "us-east-1",
                    "authorizationType": "NONE"
               }

            }
        }
    }
```

And using `CognitoAuthSession` to retrieve the `udIoken`:

```
import 'package:amplify_flutter/amplify_flutter.dart';
import 'package:amplify_auth_cognito/amplify_auth_cognito.dart';


 Future<void> fetchCognitoAuthSession() async {
  try {
    final cognitoPlugin = Amplify.Auth.getPlugin(AmplifyAuthCognito.pluginKey);
    final CognitoAuthSession  result = await cognitoPlugin.fetchAuthSession() ;
    final identityId = result.identityIdResult.value;
    final token = result.userPoolTokensResult.value.toJson();

    getTodo(token['idToken'].toString());
    
    safePrint("Current user's identity ID: $identityId");
  } on AuthException catch (e) {
    safePrint('Error retrieving auth session: ${e.message}');
  }
}

Future<void> getTodo(String token) async {
  print('token: ');
  print(token);
  try {
    final restOperation = Amplify.API.get(
      '/agenda-medica/especialidades',
       queryParameters: {
        'codHospitales': 'CLC',
      },
      apiName: 'api-clc',
      headers: {
        'x-custom-authorization': token,
        'X-Amz-Date': DateTime.now().toUtc().toIso8601String(), 
        'X-Api-Key': [**********************],
        //'X-Amz-Security-Token': accToken,
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
      },
    
      );
    final response = await restOperation.response;
    print('GET call succeeded: ${response.decodeBody()}');
  } on ApiException catch (e) {
    print('GET call failed: $e');
  }
}
```

but the error persists:

```
GET call failed: ApiException {
  "message": "{\"message\":\"Unauthorized\"}",
  "underlyingException": "HTTP Status code: 401"
}
```

HTML and JS Test:
I'm also test the function in directly in the browser with Js:

> Project Info: Flutter 3.10.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> Framework • revision f92f44110e (5 weeks ago) • 2023-06-01 18:17:33 -0500
> Engine • revision 2a3401c9bb
> Tools • Dart 3.0.3 • DevTools 2.23.1